# How can i acces this boolean in this timer?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, timer, boolean

```
 GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
                bool check =true;
              });
              if (check == true) {
              int details = -10;
```

I want to acces the boolean check in the timer in the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scope problem, as you are instantiating the `check` variable in the function inside the `Timer` callback, and it will not be accessible outside of that scope.

You can either have that variable declared in your class and access it when you need it, like this:

In the class

```
bool check;
int details;
```

---

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      setState((){
        check = true;
        details = -10;
      });
    });
  }
)
```

Or, if you don't need the check variable outside that scope, you can just remove it completely:

In the class:

```
int details;
```

---

In the Widget:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      setState((){
        details = -10;
      });
    });
  }
)
```

*I've added `setState`s in both examples as it seems like you will be updating your view with these values, and it wouldn't work without a `setState`.*

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct, to help other users. Also consider upvoting for relevance.